# Using a loop to select a varying range using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am trying to select three columns of data at a time (e.g. A:C, to row 2174) to copy into a master file, where additional calculations happen in excel. I then want to move onto the next three columns (e.g. D:F) in the original file and repeat the process. For the first part of that process, I have the following code:

```
For i = 1 To 72 Step 3

Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(2174, i + 2)).Select
Selection.Copy
```

The code stops here with the the error "Subscript Out of Range" despite the "cells" referencing the correct cells and filename inputting correctly from previous code (or when it was changed to directly reference the file name).

Any clarity on why it isn't working would be much appreciated.

---

### EDIT

I believe the error was occurring due to using the whole file directory rather than just the name, the addition of `Filename` definition has removed the "Subscript out of range" error,  but I now have a

> Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

on the `"With Workbooks(Filename).Sheet1"` line

Whole code is as follows:

```
Sub TestImport()

Dim i As Integer

'creates file directory in specified cell
DataFile = Application.GetOpenFilename

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'removes right click options
Cancel = True

'clear past data
Range("B48:D5000").ClearContents

'open data file
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=DataFile, _
    Origin:=437, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
    xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
    Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Filename = Right(DataFile, 13)

With Workbooks(Filename).Sheet1
    For i = 1 To 13 Step 3
        .Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(2174, i + 2)).Copy
        Windows("Data Processing.xlsm").Activate
        Range("B48").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
        Workbooks.Open DataFile
        ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False

        'copy key variable from front sheet to Db
        Sheets("Front Sheet").Range("F51:Z53").Copy
        Sheets("Db_KeyVariable").Range("B10000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        'copy summary into Db
        Sheets("Calculations").Range("AO4:BL15").Copy
        Sheets("Db_StrokeData").Range("B10000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Error occured because filename is incorrect, make sure you entered the correct filename.

Subscript out of range means the file does not exist.!

Comment: Thank you, that is clear! I was using the whole file directory which I think was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your error, is the `(Cells(1, i), Cells(2174, i + 2))` are not qualifed with `Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Sheet1")`.

Also, there is no need to `Select` and then use `Selection.Copy`, just copy the `Range` directly (all the `Select` is "costing" a lot of run-time).

Try the code below:

```
With Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Sheet1")
    For i = 1 To 72 Step 3
        .Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(2174, i + 2)).Copy
        ' rest of your code goes here...

    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Will this work when the master sheet I am trying to copy to is in a different workbook? I am still getting the error.

Comment: @CatherineShin is the other Workbook named `Filename` open when you run this code ? Perhaps you shoulr share the rest of your code, to find the error

Comment: @ Shai Rado  That's completely ridiculous. Submitting a comment while down voting the answer should be mandatory. There should be a rule for this scenario. Since I didn't like this behavior, I am up voting the answer to counter it.

Comment: I have now added the whole code- the initial error has gone potentially due to using the whole directory rather than filename(?) but I have a object error instead which it would be great if you could help with!